# Linux Turnkey SNMP

Tags: snmp, turnkeylinux.org

I'm running a Linux turnkey web server and I'm trying to get PHP functions such as,
snmpget()
to work on my server. It looks like I require a "apt-get install net-snmp" command to be run in order for me to use SNMP commands. but the server says "Unable to locate package net-snmp"

This is where I'm told I require Net-SNMP; http://php.net/manual/en/snmp.requirements.php

So I'm not sure how to install this?

Comment: It  looks like net-snmp isn't available from the repositories of this installation. Since this deals with package installation on a server, I would suggest asking this question on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/).

Comment: Agreed, not a programming question so not a good fit for StackOverflow.